# Provide a global access to database handler

Tags: c#, persistence

I'm developing an application in C# (but this is not relevant, since i don't want to use any language facility) and I need to handle the connection to a database. I would avoid to explicitly create the connection in each method, like:

```
private void btnAnteprima_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id=***;" +
                   "password=***;server=***;" +
                   "database=***");
    myConnection.Open();
    SqlDataReader myReader = null;
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from *** where IDCliente=*", myConnection);
    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

    while (myReader.Read())
    {
        MessageBox.Show(myReader["xyz"].ToString());
    }           
}
```

I would something like:

```
private void btnAnteprima_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    SqlReader myReader = DbFactory.ExecuteQuery("select * from *** where IDCliente=*");

    while (myReader.Read())
    {
        MessageBox.Show(myReader["xyz"].ToString());
    }           
}
```

As far as I know, the use of singleton pattern is useless or even harmfull in terms of performance. I wander about factory pattern to achieve this but i can't figure out how to do at its best. Did you have examples, paper to do this? I don't want reinvent the wheel, I just want use the right design pattern, and understand what's behind the wheel.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the fact you'using C# *is* relevant. Each language has its database abstraction APIs and dependency injection frameworks, and it's hard to give a language-agnostic best prectice. The singleton antipattern is not an aintipattern because of its performance, but because of the coupling and lack of testability that it causes.

Comment: I know this, but I would push my knowledge beyond the framework APIs and facility...

Comment: Is that a new way of saying "I want to reinvent the wheel instead of using the standard way"?

Comment: I don't want to reinvent the wheel, I just want to know how the wheel works.

Comment: Then tag the question with C# and your persistence framework, because every language/framework has its own wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Data Access Block with the Microsoft Enterprise Library.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664408(v=pandp.50).aspx